# php specifying array values? Variable passed to each() is not an array or object

Tags: php, arrays

beginner PHP programmer here trying to use the mailchimp API...

I keep getting this PHP error with regard to my first line of code here....  I am posting a value from a form, as you can see, but I am not sure what is going on.

The error:
Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in xxxxxxx on line 24 (which is the first line)

```
while (list($key, $val) = each($_POST['MCgroup'])) {
        $interest .= ($count>0 ? ", " : "");
        $interest .= $val;
        $count++;
    }

    echo $interest; //echos NOTHINGblank
    $mergeVars = array(
                       'INTERESTS'=>$interest
                        );

    echo $mergeVars; //echos the word ARRAY
```

From what I have researched, OBVIOUSLY I am not passing an actual ARRAY... but also from what I have found, my syntax all seems correct. (But I could be overlooking something).

Here is the part of the form code that is passing the values

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MCgroup" id="MCgroup" value="My Interest One" />
 <input type="hidden" name="MCgroup" id="MCgroup" value="My Interest Two" />
```

or I COULD change it to

```
<input type="hidden" name="MCgroup" id="MCgroup" value="My Interest One, My Interest Two" />
```

I just am not sure how to make THAT into an array.

Help please! Thanks!

Comment: `$_POST['MCgroup']` is likely a string, hence the warning.

Comment: You already know the problem... `$_POST['MCgroup']` is not an array, so you cannot use `each()`. What is the value of `$_POST['MCgroup']` and what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Right, $_POST['MCgroup']  is a string, just the name of a name of a person's interests in a mailing list we can call "narf" .. 

I am basically trying make an array of posted values to pass to mailchimp. On some forms, I may post 1 value, on others, I may post more.  (A person can have MULTIPLE interests)...

Comment: As above, you are using `each()` on a string that is causing your warning. As it is not fatal the while loop is ignored leaving $interest empty.

Comment: Could you post the form page as well? You somehow need to transform the `$_POST['MCgroup']` value into an array, so it's important to know what format the string is in.

Comment: I totally see what you guys mean.  I am just not sure the steps to fix it.  I think I am actually confused about my while loop.  I see now that the elements in each need to be an array, so my goal is to turn it into an array.  I have posted a section of the form code.

Comment: do this on your form `<input type="hidden" name="MCgroup[]" id="MCgroup" value="My Interest One" />`

Comment: @dqlopez, that was the ticket!  I have seen that in plenty of code too! I can't believe I didnt think of that...

So, should I create multiple elements like my first example? or just seperate the values with a comma in my second?

Comment: @PaulHanak, It depends on you. But the easy way to separate each values is by having their own hidden input. If you go to comma approach, you will have to use split string functions like `explode()` to get each value separated by comma.

Comment: @PaulHanak - if my suggestion solves your problem, might as well check my answer post as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your `<input>` to have an array name by suffixing `[]`, do something like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="MCgroup[]" id="MCgroup" value="My Interest One" />`
`<input type="hidden" name="MCgroup[]" id="MCgroup" value="My Interest Two" />`

then check it by:

`print_r($_POST['MCgroup']);`

Where I assume you set form method to POST.

Answer (score 1):

Change the HTML name to an array:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="MCgroup[]" id="MCgroup1" value="My Interest One" />
 <input type="hidden" name="MCgroup[]" id="MCgroup2" value="My Interest Two" />
 <input type="hidden" name="MCgroup[]" id="MCgroup3" value="And another sparkling interest" />
```

Also only use id if it is going to be unique.